# What do i need to add and where to send the JWT token to the browser header?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, jwt, express-jwt

I'm a new to backend and I was trying to create an authentication and authorization API. The app is working fine in Postman but I have to manually send the token. I want to send it to the header.

This is my auth.js middleware.

```js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

  const token = req.header("token");
  console.log(token)
  if (!token) return res.status(401).json({
    message: "Auth Error"
  });

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "randomString");
    req.user = decoded.user;
    next();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    res.status(500).send({
      message: "Invalid Token"
    });
  }
};
```

And this is my authentication index.js file

```js
// Filename : user.js

const express = require("express");
const {
  check,
  validationResult
} = require("express-validator");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const auth = require('../middleware/auth')
const router = express.Router();

const User = require("../model/User");


//Signup
router.get('/signup', (req, res) => {
  res.render("signup.pug")
})

router.post(
  "/signup", [
    check("username", "Please Enter a Valid Username").isLength({
      min: 5
    }),
    check("email", "Please enter a valid email").isEmail(),
    check("password", "Please enter a valid password").isLength({
      min: 7
    })
  ],
  async(req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        errors: errors.array()
      });
    }

    const username = req.body.username;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    try {
      let user = await User.findOne({
        email
      });
      if (user) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          msg: "User Already Exists"
        });
      }

      user = new User({
        username,
        email,
        password
      });

      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
      user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

      await user.save();

      const payload = {
        user: {
          id: user.id
        }
      };

      jwt.sign(
        payload,
        "randomString", {
          expiresIn: 10000
        },
        (err, token) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.status(200).json({
            token
          });
        }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
      res.status(500).send("Error in Saving");
    }
  }
);


//Login

router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.render("login.pug")
})

router.post(
  "/login", [
    check("email", "Please enter a valid email").isEmail(),
    check("password", "Please enter a valid password").isLength({
      min: 6
    })
  ],
  async(req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        errors: errors.array()
      });
    }

    const {
      email,
      password
    } = req.body;
    try {
      let user = await User.findOne({
        email
      });
      if (!user)
        return res.status(400).json({
          message: "User Not Exist"
        });

      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
      if (!isMatch)
        return res.status(400).json({
          message: "Incorrect Password !"
        });

      const payload = {
        user: {
          id: user.id
        }
      };

      jwt.sign(
        payload,
        "randomString", {
          expiresIn: 3600
        },
        (err, token) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.status(200).json({
            token
          });
        }
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      res.status(500).json({
        message: "Server Error"
      });
    }
  }
);



router.get("/me", auth, async(req, res) => {


  try {
    // request.user is getting fetched from Middleware after token authentication
    const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
    res.json(user);
  } catch (e) {
    res.send({
      message: "Error in Fetching user"
    });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Please also tell where to put in the code. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you explain your issue little more please.
are you saying sending token through header in postman is your issue?
You can use **Authorization** tab in postman if that's your issue, [link](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/authorization/).

Comment: I want to connect the API to the front end. I have done that partially only. The token has to be sent to the header of the browser but im unable to that.

Answer (score 0):

The token is supposed to be sent in the body of the login response, not in a header.

```
var token = jwt.sign(
  payload,
  "randomString",
  {
    expiresIn: 10000
  },
  (err, token) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.status(200).json({
      token
    });
  }
);

// This line should send the token to your client in the body
res.json({ token });
```

Your client receives the response from your backend and saves it locally (either in memory, a cookie or localstorage) and should use it for subsequent requests.

When making an authenticated request from your client, only then you should add the token to your Authorization header.

Comment: Thanks! I think that was the problem. I didn't render the route with the token as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this after signing the token.

```
res.render('/(Page Route)',{token: token});
```